# MOOC or other online class for advanced stats?

Tags: self-study

Are there any MOOC or other (free/cheap) online classes for advanced statistics? I'm thinking upper-level undergrad or introductory graduate level. Things like time series models, factor analysis, MLE, Bayesian statistics, etc.

Comment: I am interested in the answer as well, in particular I look for an intro course on bayesian statistics.

Comment: This question has a very short time frame, so answering it even with a great list of courses that will be offered in the next couple of months won't help the "eternity" knowledge. Most MOOCs can be audited later, but to receive credit, you usually have to enroll concurrently.

Comment: As far as i am concerned, I do not mind of credits. As you say, most MOOCs can be audited later and therefore can allow self-learning.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know about advanced course, but awaiting another answer, it worth taking the opportunity to share these links:

- A review of stastics with R (introductory) courses in english:

[MOOCs and courses to learn R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/moocs-and-courses-to-learn-r/)

- An Statistics with R (introductory) course in French (covers basic statistics and linear modeling up to ANOVA plus survival analysis):

[Link to the course presentation](http://bioecologie.over-blog.com/2014/03/introduction-a-la-statistique-avec-r-des-cours-gratuits.html)

[Link to the course videos on youtube](http://goo.gl/IvdSyp)

Answer (score 3):

Nick Horton has compiled a list of MOOC courses that are offered in the summer of 2014: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/upcoming-statistics-data-science-related-152247.S.5878156475607576578